# Determine SQL Server query (stored procedure) result type

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm, code-generation

I am planning to organize my data in SQL Server as a small orm of my own, creating classes of meta data on each in my code.

For the tests I am hard-coding the objects, the next step is to generate the properties of each using SQL Server queries about those objects.

And now that I deal with the stored procedures section of my code in C#,
I was wondering how it is possible to somehow use SQL Server to query the result type of the command executed?

For example, here we know what it's doing even by reading its name ...

```
[dbo].[GtallDrLFilesCount]
```

but another could select some other type of return such as rowset string etc'

Using the above stored procedure will return an int :

```
if(@AllDrives=1) Begin 
        Select 
          * From [dbo].[HddFolderFiles]
End
```

but the next (above) selects all content rather the RowsCount

I was planning to access SQL Server and query it's objects, and as I do not plan to set return parameter (OUT), is there a more elegant way to achieve it, rather than parsing the `.sql` file of the stored procedure?

Like if text contains `SELECT *` (this is a rowset) expect it with `DataTable`
if text contains `Select COUNT(*)` (this is int) prepare int type variable.

I thought in the case I did not assign an out parameter to my stored procedures can SQL Server tell the return type somehow even though it has no `out` parameter to make it easy for it?

Comment: I would suggest you change as many stored procedures as possible to stored functions.  The return type is then specified as part of the definition.

Comment: @marc_s hey marc, found the time to reply,  there's a lesson(s) / added value, taken in these 'experiments'  i am coding, ..all so with little hope that i will find faster and /or more customized  / better approach but mostly is for my experience. i find it very educational to try tackle many interesting builtin modules in .net and some of the extensions from bunch of chosen authors   and categories of API's i am learning a lot about technique  on the way learning from the bests.

Comment: @marc_s looking @ your record, i think i will never get to your XP but i will get close much faster than taking all the courses and lessons you have made the effort to take and educate your self, added to it is the experience from projects you've participated in through your Career, my approach is to save that effort (: and do it by my self, it's kind a shortcut  i am willing to take compared to what you have sacrificed, in "your time" it was not easy (as it's now.. stack overflow is around) and some more extra improved resources, imagine if someone like you would started his career now.

Comment: @marc_s, if those ORM's didn't reinvent the wheel again and again -> infinity, there wouldn't be plenty of them, there would be only one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to execute the SProc to get it's columns, but you could do it without actually returing data using `set fmtonly`

Even sprocs that return a single value (eg - int) return a table when you use c# ... so you just need to take a look at the reader's Columns to get the data you want.

So:

```
set fmtonly on
exec [dbo].[MyStoredProc] 0
set fmtonly off
```

Will return a recordset which you can examine in c#

```
var adoCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_sConnectStr);
var adoCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("your SQL (above)", adoCon);

var Rows = adoCmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dtSchema = Rows.GetSchemaTable();
```

Now - you can wander through dtSchema to get columns.  It's not pure SQL, but it's a c# + SQL approach. `[dbo].[GtallDrLFilesCount]` will return a single column table (column of type int).

Obviously - use a SQL command (not string). The next trick is translating SQL types into native c# types (easy for some data types and tricky for others ... take a look at ADOCommand's `ReturnProviderSpecificTypes` option).

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes sure it does help, so fmtonly in sql for Sproc,  is similar to SchemaOnly in C# command type it does execute but without data content, so read it via sqldatareader to see column DataType will be a good ide ! i think it's a correct answer , i will give it some more time to sink in  before i decide though (: thanks !

Comment: now i don't know which is the approach i will take as from 15 minutes ago @lad2025 added his answer, i will try them both soon enough, thanks a lot for now both two of you !!

Answer (score 1):

From `SQL Server 2012+` you can use [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) to read metadata about resultset:

> This dynamic management function takes a Transact-SQL statement as a
>   parameter and describes the metadata of the first result set for the
>   statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
   N'EXEC [dbo].[MyProcedure]', NULL, 0);

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
   N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tab]', NULL, 0);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9d0f/2/0)**</kbd>

This method has limitation for more info read [Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

Comment: this is greate as i have saved for later use to implement on the Server Table Objects another  more complicated approach to get the same results querying sys table objects and their structure and this code for the table objects and return type of stored procedure could both use that code, now all i need is for the next step(not included in this question) is  the parameters and rest releavant meta on each **Sproc object** such sproc name , and parameters as u do with table and cols .

Comment: and found that Sproc Meta Data Query too somewhere around the link you posted above : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ9